# Left join could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I have this tables:

```
WS | Cat | Prod | CS | Dis| UserWS | MarA | ModA | MarU | BCIU
```

I need to join them in order to get all the rows relations even if some are nulls, I tried this:

```
Select *
FROM WS 
Left join MarU on MarU.Code=WS.used_brand
Left join Prod p on p.MarA=Cat.OID 
Left join CS on WS.CS =CS.OID  
Left join Prod pp on WS.product_code=pp.Code 
Left join MarA on WS.customer_car_brand=MarA.Code 
Left join ModA on WS.customer_car_model=ModA.Code
Left join CS c on c.UserWS=UserWS.Oid 
Left join CS css on css.Dis=Dis.OID
Left join BCIU on BCIU.Code=WS.used_bci
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Cat.OID" could
>   not be bound. 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier
>   "UserWS.Oid" could not be bound. 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part
>   identifier "Dis.OID" could not be bound. 42000 - [SQL Server]The
>   multi-part identifier "Cat.Name" could not be bound. 42000 - [SQL
>   Server]The multi-part identifier "Prod.Name" could not be bound. 42000
>   - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Dis.Nombre" could not be bound. 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "UserWS.Nombre"
>   could not be bound. 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier
>   "Cat.Segmento" could not be bound.

What I'm missing?

Comment: The fact that you haven't included `Cat` in a `JOIN` anywhere, I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message is actually multiple errors. I deal with them in turn.

See the lines starting with `-->` :

```
[Err] 
42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Cat.OID" could not be bound.
 --> Your SQL doesn't mention JOIN Cat table anywhere

42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "UserWS.Oid" could not be bound. 
 --> Your SQL doesn't mention JOIN UserWS table anywhere

42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Dis.OID" could not be bound. 
 --> Your SQL doesn't mention JOIN Dis table anywhere

42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Cat.Name" could not be bound. 
 --> Your SQL doesn't mention JOIN Cat table anywhere

42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Prod.Name" could not be bound. 
 --> Your SQL doesn't call the Prod table "Prod", it joins it twice and aliases it as "p" and "pp". refer to p.Name or pp.Name, not Prod.Name

42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Dis.Nombre" could not be bound. 
 --> Your SQL doesn't mention JOIN Dis table anywhere

42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "UserWS.Nombre" could not be bound. 
 --> Your SQL doesn't mention JOIN UserWS table anywhere

42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Cat.Segmento" could not be bound.
 --> Your SQL doesn't mention JOIN Cat table anywhere
```

Answer (score 2):

First, simplify the query, to isolate the error.  You'll get the same error on:

```
SELECT *
FROM WS Left join
     MarU
     on MarU.Code = WS.used_brand Left join
     Prod p
     on p.MarA = Cat.OID
```

As the error suggests, `Cat` is undefined.  This is not a forward reference problem, because `Cat` is not defined anywhere in the `FROM` clause.  Presumably, you just left out the relevant table/view.

Answer (score 1):

```
Left join Prod p on p.MarA=Cat.OID
```

Cat in the above statement has to be a Table or a Table alias, but you don't have neither table nor alias in your statement called Cat.

Add `LEFT JOIN CAT on [ForeignKey]=CAT.[PrimaryKey]` before hand.